# How to use multiple models in MVC3 asp

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

If I have an MVC3 ASP.net page which contains a the model "`iEnumerable<mymodel.CarsForHire>`" - which links directly into an entity framework model- and I also now want to include the default user management model that MVC3 generates, how can I use both models at once?

I assume I will have to pass a collection in, or create a model called "`blah`" which has a field "carsforHire" which marries up to `iEnumerable<mymodel.CarsForHire>`, but not sure where to start.

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You already mentioned the solution; create a view model class that holds all the required data. For example:

```
public class SomeViewModel
{ 
   public User CurrentUser { get; set; }
   public IEnumerable<mymodel.CarsForHire> Cars { get; set; }
}
```

Construct that model in the controller and pass it to your view. And don't forget to update the type declaration at the top of your view.

Comment: Ah, fantastic - I thought it would be harder that that.

Answer (score 1):

What I usually do is create a ViewModel class. For example:

```
public class CarsViewModel
{
    public IEnumerable<mymodel.CarsForHire> CarsForHire { get; set; }

    public UserModel User { get; set; }
}
```

Then create the view with `CarsViewModel` instead of `IEnumerable<mymodel.CarsForHire>`

Answer (score 0):

You can use Navigational properties of EF if you want to.
i.e

```
public class carForHire()
{
 int property1{get; set;}
 .
 .
 .
//Navigationla property
public virtual blah blah { get; set; }
}
```

at your page/view you can acces it like

```
@foreach(var item in Mode)
  {
 item.blah.blahProperty
  }
```